# How to get value from radio button when it was checked?

Tags: jquery

I have more than 2 Radio buttons and want to populate the value of "showtype_cost" when a radio button is checked. and change the value when another is checked

```
<body>
   <input name="showtype" type="radio" id="basic" value="basic" />Basic Slideshow<br />

   <input name="showtype" type="radio" id="lovestory" value="lovestory" /> Love Story <br />

   <input name="showtype_cost" type="text" id="text" value="">
   <p></p>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'realise value'?

Comment: using the same name for more than one element is not a good practice.

Comment: @asprin I think he meant release the value, but after a radio button is checked, only another can be checked, it cannot be unchecked

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com For radio buttons, isn't it necessary to use the same name so that only one radio button can be selected at a time?

Comment: @aspirin: you're right. I overlooked the fact it's radio group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method, it may help you.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#basic").click(function(){
$("#text").attr("value","150");
});
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#lovestory").click(function(){
$("#text").attr("value","500");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input name="showtype" type="radio" id="basic" value="basic" />Basic Slideshow<br />

<input name="showtype" type="radio" id="lovestory" value="lovestory" /> Love Story <br />

<input name="showtype_cost" type="text" id="text" value="100">
<p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:radio[name="showtype"]').change(function(){
    $('input:text[name="showtype_cost"]').val($('input:radio[name="showtype"]:checked').val());
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('*[name=showtype]').click(function(){
        $("#text").val($(this).val());
        });
    });
});
```